# trigger ajax from link_to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button on my home page which I would like to trigger some ajax so that I can see a form on my home page when the button is pressed. This works for two of my buttons but not the third and I can't figure out why? When I press the button it redirects to root, presumably because I am using '#'. However this does trigger the correct ajax (see below) - I know this as I get a console response from the ajax success. If I change the url in the ajax to controller/new then I get the new form correctly shown in the home page. So it looks as though the controller action is being directed to root for some reason I don't understand

Here's the button

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <%= link_to image_tag("arrow.jpg"),'#', id: 'ChallengeListButton'%>
            <div id="challengeListCentre"></div>
        </div>
```

Here's the ajax it triggers (in `application.js`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#ChallengeListButton').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "challenges/index",
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
              $('#challengeListCentre').html(response);
          }
        })
      });
});
```

Here's the controller `challenges_controller.rb`

```
class ChallengesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_challenge, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /challenges
  # GET /challenges.json
  def index
    @challenges = Challenge.all
    render :layout => false
  end
end
```

Here's the views/challenges/index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'index' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', challenges_path %>
```

and the partial:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Challenges</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pointsspend</th>
      <th>Rules</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= challenge.pointsSpend %></td>
        <td><%= challenge.rules %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', challenge %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_challenge_path(challenge) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', challenge, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Challenge', new_challenge_path %>
```

and the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :challenges, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index, :edit, :destroy]
  resources :entries

resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
    member do
      post :reply
      post :restore
      post :mark_as_read
    end
    collection do
      delete :empty_trash
    end
  end

resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]

get '/messages/new/:id', to: 'messages#new'


root to: 'users#index'
  devise_for :users

  get '/users/relations', to: 'users#relations'
  post '/users/create', to: 'users#create'
  resources :users

end
```

Comment: Does console show any errors?

Comment: I have updated the question as above. The console writes a response so the correct ajax is firing but the response is the html of the whole root page rather than the index for challenges so I think challenges/index action is being interpreted as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Turns out i was being dumb. The reason it goes to root by default is because the ajax url is challenge/index when in fact it should be challenge on its own because that defaults to index as per the rake routes. On top of it I've been caught out by that before..I'll never learn

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `preventDefault()`, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ChallengeListButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // add this line

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "challenges/index",
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        $('#challengeListCentre').html(response);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. No it still has the same behaviour with your suggestion.

Comment: OK. Turns out i was being dumb. The reason it goes to root by default is because the ajax url is challenge/index when in fact it should be challenge on its own because that defaults to index as per the rake routes. On top of it I've been caught out by that before..I'll never learn